# How to return SCOPE_IDENTITY as value to use in angular app

Tags: sql, asp.net, angular

I'm struggling to return the ID of my newly inserted table row for further use in my Angular app.

Any suggestions on how to send it while I'm posting? Can't wrap my head around it.

```
public string Post(Profile profile)
{
        try
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Profile([ProfileName], [FName], [LName], [DateOfJoining], [Type], [LogoFile]) VALUES(@f1, @f2, @f3, @f4, @f5, @f6)";
            query += " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BillingApp"].ConnectionString))
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@f1", profile.ProfileName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@f2", profile.FName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@f3", profile.LName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@f4", profile.DateOfJoining));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@f5", profile.Type));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@f6", profile.LogoFile));
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                profile.ProfileID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                da.Fill(table);
            }

            return "Added successfully!";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "failed to Add";
        }
}
```

This is how I trigger it from Angular:

```
addProfile(val:any) {
    return this.http.post(this.APIUrl + '/Profile',val);
}
```

Comment: I would normally do this using a stored procedure.The sql stored procedure can return the identity value, you can call it using `connection.ExecuteNonQuery()` which avoids the expensive dataAdapter just get the return value from the connection's parameters collection. you can then return it to the client, probably in a json object along with the success status.

Comment: Thanks that helped me now i get the value returned :D

Comment: Nice- I'll add it as a proper answer below in that case for you to accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something you can implement using the return parameter from a SQL Stored Procedure.

This can then negate the need to use an expensive `DataAdapter` object to return a recordset where you only need the single Identity value.

Simply create your insert statement as a `Stored Procedure`, return the `Identity` value and call it using the `connection.executeNonQuery()` method. You can then access the return value using the `parameters` collection.